# Bash: Hide global variable using local variable with same name

Tags: bash, scope

I'd like to use a global variable in a function but don't want the change to go outside the function. So I defined a local variable initialized to the value of the global variable. The global variable has a great name, so I want to use the same name on the local variable. This seems doable in Bash, but I'm not sure if this is undefined behavior.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=3
echo $a
foo() {
    local a=$a  ##  defined or undefined?
    a=4
    echo $a
}
foo
echo $a
```

Gives output:

```
3
4
3
```

Comment: really strange question. Why not try yourself to see what happen like that : a=3;echo $a;foo(){ local a=$((a-2)); echo $a ; a=4;echo $a;};foo;echo $a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expansion happen before assignment (early on) as the [documentation states](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION):

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.

So the behavior should be predictable (and defined). In `local a=$a` when expanding `$a` it's still the global one. The command execution (assignment/declaration) happens later (when `$a` has already been replaced by its value).

However I am not sure this would not get confusing to have essentially two different variables (scope dependent) with the same name (i.e. appearing to be the one and same). So, I'd rather question wisdom of doing so on coding practices / readability / ease of navigation grounds.

Comment: Even if expansion comes first, this alone does not guarantee the statement `local a=$a` runs as expected. Some language doesn't even allow such a statement if `a` is a global variable. There needs to be references to bash scoping rule, about which I found little in its man page.

Comment: Actually, it does, because the assignment/declaration (when performed) simply is: `local a=4` (and where did the value come from really doesn't matter, at that point the information is gone). Other languages are of little relevance really. And to boot scoping in bash is rather basic.

Comment: I'd like reference to *scoping in bash is rather basic* to assure myself that `$a` as in `local a=$a` really points to the global var, though I almost believe this is true.

Comment: [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) really is probably the best you'll find.

Comment: Dynamic scoping is fun scoping: `unset` can unset a variable at outer scope and reveal another at outer-outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new shell option in Bash 5.0, [`localvar_inherit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), to have local variables with the same name inherit the value of a variable with the same name in the preceding scope:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s localvar_inherit

myfunc() {
    local globalvar
    echo "In call: $globalvar"
    globalvar='local'
    echo "In call, after setting: $globalvar"
}

globalvar='global'
echo "Before call: $globalvar"
myfunc
echo "After call: $globalvar"
```

with the following output:

```
Before call: global
In call: global
In call, after setting: local
After call: global
```

If you don't have Bash 5.0, you have to set the value in the function, as you did in your question, with the same result.